# GFI Breaker at Subpanel - Does it need a separate neutral to the main box

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a Subpanel in an outbuilding.  I've got two hots, a neutral, and a ground going back to the main.  I want to install a GFI breaker at the Subpanel and use one of the hots.  Do I need to run a separate neutral for the GFI breaker or am I okay using the one neutral for the GFI breaker and the the non-GFI breaker?  Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Hook up the GFCI in the usual way, entirely inside the sub-panel.

That is to say, hook the GFCI's pigtail to the **neutral** bus on the sub-panel, then wire hot and neutral from that circuit into the GFCI breaker.  Do not connect the GFCI's pigtail to the ground bus on the sub-panel (even if that's what you normally do in the main panel).  Do not run a separate neutral back to the main panel.

Answer (score 1):

You run a single neutral in this case.  A GFCI doesn't care about what's on the line side of it.